# There was a problem when trying to go to the article page

Tags: reactjs, redux

My route from App component:

```
<Route path="/articles/:id" component={ArticleDetail} />
```

My component:

```
class ArticleDetail extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        articleId: props.match.params.id,
        article: this.props.articleDetail(props.match.params.id),
    };
}

// componentDidMount() {
//     this.props.articleDetail(this.state.articleId)
// };

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.articleDetail(this.state.articleId)
};

render() {
    console.log('state', this.state);
    console.log('props', this.props);
    return (
        <div className="article-container">
            <h3 className="article-headline">{this.state.article.headline}</h3>
            {
                this.state.article.img_name &&
                <img src={require('../images/articles/' + this.state.article.img_name)} alt=""/>
            }
            <p className="article-description">{this.state.article.description}</p>
            <p>
                <span>Published at {this.state.article.created} by </span>
                <span className="username">{this.state.article.author.username}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    articles: state.articles,
    article: state.article,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    articleDetail: (id) => {
        dispatch(articles.articleDetail(id)).then((res) => {console.log('fetch', res)});
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleDetail);
```

console.log from mapDispatchToProps returned my article from api:
{type: "GET_ARTICLE", article: {…}}

my reducer:

```
import {FETCH_ALL_ARTICLES, GET_ARTICLE} from "../constants";


const initialState = [];

export default function articles(state=initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_ALL_ARTICLES:
      return [...state, ...action.articles];

    case GET_ARTICLE:
      // return [...action.article];
      console.log(action.article);
      return action.article;

   default:
     return state;
  }
}
```

But I don't get the data in the component either in the props or in the state. 
As you can see from the code, I tried to create it using two different hooks and directly in the constructor. I hope for your help. What am I doing?

Comment: Can you show the reducer?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added a reducer

Comment: I suggest that you install the React and Redux development tools for Chrome. These will allow you to inspect component props and state and the redux store state. They will help you determine if your actions, reducers, and mapStateToProps are working correctly to send data where it is supposed to go.

Comment: You don't have a "article" state in the reducer, just an "articles". So, in "state.article" inside "mapStateToProps" will always return undefined. You need to distinguis "articles" (all articles) and "article" (selected one) in your state and reducer

Comment: and i have one more question i can assign:
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.articleDetail(this.state.articleId, this.setState({article: 'string'}))
    }

But can I immediately assign what this function returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mapStateToProps`, you have a reference to `state.article`, but it's `undefined`. You need to create the key `article` in state. In the reducer:

```
const initialState = {};

export default function articles(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_ALL_ARTICLES:
      return { ...state, { articles: action.articles } };

    case GET_ARTICLE:
      return { ...state, { article: action.article } };

   default:
     return state;
  } 

}
```

And in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    articles: state.articles,
    article: state.article,
  }
};
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: did not work unfortunately. mapDispatchToProps return me object. When im reload page in console log i see response becouse if im right in article: this.props.articleDetail(props.match.params.id) i caused it. But in render console.log(this.state) returned undefined

Comment: Ohh, also does not work. I already do not understand anything. By the way, I can not transfer from the reducer(((

Comment: The answer with the API is returned to me exactly. I did the console log in the reducer, it also returns the article, but why can not I get it in props already in the component itself

Comment: https://github.com/rRaijin/react-trainee/blob/master/front/src/App.js#L23 here creating store

Comment: In mapStateToProps, try `articles: state.articles.articles` and `article: state.articles.article,`,

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqgUf.png

Comment: I guess I already tortured you, but nothing comes out (((Surprisingly, the Notes component does the same as fetches, and with the help of ComponentDidMount I get a list of articles in props when rendering

Comment: I tried to get the state in MapStateToProps:
Returned all clear arrays from state except auth...

can this somehow be due to the fact that I myself have indicated the route in App.js. 
and there I get only auth in MapStateToProps. 
But on the other hand, I don't get notes there either.

Comment: Yes, you were right. To my great shame, I did not bother to read the documentation first. The problem was that I did not remove the code that caused the error in the render () method. 
as soon as I did it, and indicated in the reducer:      
case GET_ARTICLE:
      return action.article;
in component:
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.articleDetail(this.state.articleId)
    }
end in mapStateToProps:
    return {
        article: state.articles,
    } 
I got in this.props.article my object. Thanks you and sorry))